# Scheme: What does this function evaluate to?

Tags: lambda, scheme, evaluate

```
(define test
     (lambda()
       (let* ((x 1)
              (y 3)
              (z 5)
              (foo (lambda (n)
                     (let* ((x 3)
                            (y (+ x n))
                            (g (lambda(w) (+ (* x w) y))))
                       g))))
        ((foo 10) x))))
```

What does this evaluate to?

Attempt:

Call `(foo 10)` -> `(lambda(w) (+ x w) y)`, where x = 3, y = 13

Call `((lambda(w) (+ (* x w) y) x)` -> (where local x is 1) ->

Comment: The parentheses in the first `let*` are wrong, so it's impossible to tell what it's supposed to do. Please fix it up.

Comment: I hope the new edit helped. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(foo 10) => (lambda (w) (+ (* x w) y) ; where x = 3 and y = 13
         => (lambda (w) (+ (* 3 w) 13)

((foo 10) x) => (+ (* 3 w) 13) ; where w is 1
             => (+ (* 3 1) 13)
             => 16
```

[See here](http://repl.it/Iij)

Don't know where you got 52 from.